# How can I add an app to a Facebook community page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I'm a developer for a media website that has a facebook app

People can add the app (used for facebook login)
The app is also attached to one of our community pages and has been for quite a while (used to post to that community page via the facebook api)

We have since created several other community pages but since the timeline change I can't figure out how to add our app to these community pages (to do more automated posts)

I've tried https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID while accessing facebook as the community page (via the top right dropdown menu) but only get the error:

You are using Facebook as COMMUNITY_PAGE_NAME
To access this page, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as your page to using Facebook as yourself.

I've searched around and it seems that often Facebook has broken features. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this while logged in as the admin of the page; not while logged in as the page itself - the dialog will show a list of pages you admin

Comment: Now I feel dumb. I had the right link and everything. Thanks, this really helped.